# PHP Curl fields

Tags: php

I am trying to implement the TNT labels API and it wants to send an access token in the request.

I sent the access token code as a POST Field but it didnot work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

I sent the access token as a post field but it didnot work and returned error
"{ "error": "invalid_request", "description": "The required parameter access token is missing." }"

```
function httpPostRequest($url, $strRequest,$auth)
        {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strRequest);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $access_token);
        $isSecure = strpos($url, "https://");
        if ($isSecure === 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        }

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->errorCode = curl_errno($ch);
        $this->errorMessage = curl_error($ch);
        return $result;
        }
```

Expected: should return a success message
Actual :  `{ "error": "invalid_request", "description": "The required parameter access token is missing." }`

Comment: NZ Post api says to send it like this


curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \   
'https://api.nzpost.co.nz/{API CALL}'

Comment: the curl option -H means you have to pass the parameter as header, not like post field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H option means you should pass parameter in the header.

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
function httpPostRequest($url, $strRequest,$auth)
    {

    $fields = array(
        'strRequest' => $strRequest,
        'access_token' => $access_token
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $isSecure = strpos($url, "https://");
    if ($isSecure === 0) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    }

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->errorCode = curl_errno($ch);
    $this->errorMessage = curl_error($ch);
    return $result;
    }
```